# How to create a "standard" CDF programmatically?

Tags: export, notebooks, cdf-format

How can I programmatically create a CDF which is similar to the CDFs created by `File -> CDF Export -> Standalone...`?  `Export` supports CDFs but it does not use the same options as File -> Export... and it does not seem to allow setting the `WindowSize` which I also need.

---

My current solution is the following (ugly):

```
manip = Manipulate[Plot[k x, {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 5}, SaveDefinitions -> True]

Export["file.cdf", 
  doc = CreateDocument[manip,
    ScrollingOptions -> {"VerticalScrollRange" -> Fit}, 
    ShowCellBracket -> False, 
    Deployed -> True, CellContext -> Notebook, 
    TrackCellChangeTimes -> False]];

NotebookClose[doc]
```

Comment: Why not CDFDeploy["G:\\tmp\\test.cdf", manip, Method -> "Standalone"]

Comment: @Rolf That is what I needed ... I never seriously worked with CDF before ...  Actually this is not mentioned on the "How to create CDF" page, nor on the page describing the CDF export format.

Comment: @Rolf If you post that as an answer, I'll adapt the question to it.  Or do you think I should just delete it?

Comment: The documentation is sufficiently strange that one does not immediately find CDFDeploy. So let's just keep it maybe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CDFDeploy["G:\\tmp\\test.cdf", manip, Method -> "Standalone"]
```

does what is needed.

It also supports setting the `WindowSize` option.

Unfortunately this [introduction to CDF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html) does not mention `CDFDeploy` as a function.
One has to arrive [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/Standalone.html)
to find [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CDFDeploy.html).

Comment: However, it looks like that for more control (say, you want to have WindowsMargins settings saved in thd CDF), the Epxort method is to be preferred over CDFDeploy (which seems to overwrite any explicit WindowMargins settings).